# PERFEX CRM - Server has updated to PHP 8. Media Folder is now blank

Tags: php, codeigniter

My hosting provider does not support PHP version 7.4, I have attempted to update Perfex which has been a nightmare. Since the upgrade to version 8.0, I cannot access /utilities/media. Does anyone have a quick fix to get this working without having to install an entire new version of perfex.

I have attempted to update the 4 update files but it requests a new installation.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the error log first. Im using all functions without problems in PHP8.

If you are using CPANEL, you can check it in the main root dir of the app, or checking generated errors on Metric > Errors